# Visual Studio 2008 started using C++ syntax when debugging a C# project!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

Has anyone ever experienced this ?

[VS 2008 bug http://files.sauliaus.info/vs2008_bug.png](http://files.sauliaus.info/vs2008_bug.png)

Out of the blue, Visual Studio 2008 started using C++ syntax when debugging a C# project, even though I've probably never even opened a C++ project on this computer (it's installed though). Restarting visual studio and the computer does not help, is there a way out of this without reinstalling Visual Studio ?

Comment: As expected, the problem disappeared randomly the same way it appeared. Still, I'm leaving this question simply out of curiosity as to why it happened and for future references if someone is to encounter this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's awesome.  I would give my left pinkie if I knew how to turn on that option on demand.  It isn't C++ syntax btw, it is C++/CLI, the managed language version of C++.  Do you have any C++/CLI code in your project?  You are also debugging a 64-bit program, that uses a very different debugger.  The debugging 'experience' is usually much better if you force the debug build of your program to run in 32-bit mode.  Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target = x86.  Also enables Edit+Continue.

There's a [post-SP1 hotfix](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB967631) for the VS2008 debugger.  It fixes *many* debugger problems.

Comment: I know it's C++/CLI - no need to be picky :) And no, I don't have any C++/CLI code in my project. I also don't know whether the proposed hotfix fixes this issue, since as I've already stated, the problem solved itself, nevertheles, I'm accepting this answer because of the proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting your settings to Visual C# Developer (Tools, Import & Export Settings).
Export your current settings (in the second step) in case you want them back.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the values "normally" or as Hex. There should be a toggle button labeled "Hex" in your toolbar. Turn it off.

Comment: That wouldn't change the "System::Object^" though.

Comment: The screenshot had hex turned off, the hex numbers are pointers I think - normal values were not shown in hex.